# How to have input options be key/value pairs in github actions

Tags: github-actions

I have 3 servers that are options of an input `server_name` but I want the the user sellecting the options to only see server names like `server_1`, `server_2` & `server_3` but server 1-3 should have values like instance IDs. Here's the code:

```
name: test

on: 
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      server_name:
        description: The server where you wish to deploy & test your code.
        required: true
        type: choice
        options:
          - server_1: i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
          - server_2: i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
          - server_3: i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

IDK if my syntax here `server_1: i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` is correct & I have not seen any examples of this.
perhaps I need to create some additional logic to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure and access these values as environment variables like in the following example:

```
name: test

on: 
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      server_name:
        description: The server where you wish to deploy & test your code.
        required: true
        type: choice
        options:
        - server_1
        - server_2
        - server_3

env:
  server_1: "i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  server_2: "i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  server_3: "i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo ${{ env[inputs.server_name] }}
```

To read more about `env` context, visit [Contexts article](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#env-context)